# Android: Single service with multiple threads

Tags: android, service

I am building an application which performs 3 tasks concurrently.->

1. Listening to new devices.
2. A proxy to interact with the device in real-time.
3. A set of business Logic to be run on the data provided by the device proxies.
4. And of couse a Main UI (thread)

I want task 1,2 and 3 to run even when the application is in the **background**.

What should be done?

1. Using 3 services, one for each.. (apparently not practical).
2. Can a single service support all the tasks.( one service with multiple threads sort of design)?

Please help.

Basically, What i intend to ask is that is a model available to perform all 3 tasks even if the application is in the **background**? If service is the answer, how can it be implemented in an efficient way without putting too much load on the system i.e. using 3 services?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for three threads started in your action or (Surface)View depending on what sort of updates you'll have on screen.

When doing threads though you really need to keep synchronization in mind so your application won't blow up from accessing the same variables and getting unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks Jon,
The threads will stop working as soon as the android kills the Main UI activity(activity in background).
How do we keep the threads going even if application is in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Using Multiple Threads to perform your tasks concurrently.

The following link gives a good idea about Multiple threads: http://edwards.sdsu.edu/labsite/index.php/josh/124-multiple-background-threads-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the link chiran.
But I want these threads to be run even when the application is in the background. Can you suggest something on that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your service runs in the foreground; this will make it work.